# Как использовать mysql в django?

Tags: mysql, python, django

Использую django с python3. При `pip install mysql-python` выдает ошибку: `Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-kgys_quh/mysql-python/`. Пробовал делать из `venv`, тоже самое

Answer (score 1):

Вы бы выложили полный лог с ошибками, было бы понятнее почему у вас не работает.

Есть два способа использования mysql в python.

## Вариант 1. Как пишут во всех статьях

Дело в том, что все коннекторы к базам необходимо компилировать ввиду их конструктивных особенностей. Конечно же в случае использования pip он делает это за вас. Однако в вашей системе должны быть заголовочные файлы для компиляции. Вы не указали систему, поэтому для debian-based систем в т.ч. ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip python-dev libmysqlclient-dev
```

Далее необходимо повторить установку через pip

```
pip install MySQL-python
```

## Вариант 2. Более правильный

Дело в том, что мейнтейнеры не дураки и всё собрали за вас. Соответственно вам надо установить пакет из репозитория, который содержит уже скомпилированный mysql-python.

Для debian-based опять же команда следующая:

```
sudo apt-get install python-mysqldb
```

Если у вас python3, тогда пакет немного другой:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-mysqldb
```

После этого у вас глобально появится модуль для подключения к mysql.

Однако это не всё. Если вы используете virtualenv (или venv в python3), то необходимо создать виртуальное окружение так, чтобы оно включало в себя глобальные пакеты. Делается это командой `virtualenv venv --system-site-packages` (или для python3 `python3 -m venv --system-site-packages`). После этого оно будет включать как глобальные пакеты, так и установленные непосредственно в окружение. Ставить через `pip` такие пакеты не нужно, ровно как и выносить их в файл requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Ввожу

```py
python -m venv --system-site-packages
```

Выдаёт

```
usage: venv [-h] [--system-site-packages] [--symlinks | --copies] [--clear] [--upgrade] [--without-pip]    
            [--prompt PROMPT] [--upgrade-deps]    
            ENV_DIR [ENV_DIR ...]    
venv: error: the following arguments are required: ENV_DIR
```

Comment: Ваш пост не является ответом. Он будет удален. Если у Вас возник вопрос - нажмите на кнопку [Задать вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), опишите Вашу проблему и опубликуйте.

Comment: Если у вас возник новый вопрос, пожалуйста, задайте его при помощи кнопки «[Задать вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)». Если нужно указать контекст, дайте ссылку на этот вопрос. — [из очереди проверок](/review/late-answers/845580)